# Connection string not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database using C#, both the server and program are on the same computer. When I try to connect I get an exception:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
```

There is an inner exception simply saying `{"The parameter is incorrect"}`.

I'm trying to connect using this

```
<add name="KBLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.KBL.csdl|res://*/Models.KBL.ssdl|res://*/Models.KBL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=\sql8dvlp1\v01;initial catalog=KBL;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

any idea what parameter is incorrect?

Comment: Do you have build the connections tring on your own? Maybe you can try to build a connection string over visual studio.

Comment: The server name shouldn't start with a \

Comment: @BendEg it's not my connection string, It came with TFS so just trying to make it work on my pc

Comment: @DavidG yea replaced it with &quot;

Comment: Also are you sure you need to be using a connection string in that format or do you just need a "normal" string such as `data source=sql8dvlp1\v01;initial catalog=KBL;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework`?

Comment: @Steve error changes to 5 then. but it remains

Comment: @DavidG what do you mean?  I have no clue why the string is build like that I know it uses a a `.edmx` file

Comment: @Kiwi well it depends on what is consuming the connection string, but EDMX probably needs it that way. By the way, you don't need a quote in before the server name, remove it so it looks like this `...data source=sql8dvlp1...`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same credentials as windows for the dataBase also?
Have you tried with **integrated security=false** and explicitly providing user Name and Password?

are you able to connect that way?

Also, try with providing data source as data source="(local)"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx